# How to get float values from a MySQL database into a Datatable | C#

Tags: c#, mysql

In my database I have one columns in which the data is saved as float 
I now want to export this and other columns from my database into a datatabel and then convert each column of the datatable to a list. 
This workes fine for  every column expect the one which is filled whit float values. 

My code: 
Getting the database into a Datatable:

```
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataset);
DataTable dt= dataset.Tables[0];
```

Converting the data from the datatable to a list ("Nutzfläche" is the column which includees the float values):

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       string s_roomRoomNr = row["Raumnr"].ToString();
       ls_roomRoomNr.Add(s_roomRoomNr);
       string s_roomRoomUser = row["Raumbereich Nutzer"].ToString();
       ls_roomRoomUser.Add(s_roomRoomUser);
       string s_roomRoomArea = row["Nutzfläche"].ToString();
       ls_roomRoomArea.Add(s_roomRoomArea);
    }
```

This workes fine untill I get to s_roomRoomArea, then it throws an exeption 
Exeptiontype: System.ArgumentException

Comment: Can you put the exception string here?

Comment: @Lucifer do you mean with "exception string" my code or the error message?

Comment: If you are getting an exception please always include the entire exception detail in the question. Is it a NullReferenceException by any chance? You should check your row column values for null before trying to call ToString().

Comment: It is a System.ArgumentException

Comment: And the rest of the exception detail? It is there for a reason, we can't run your code, you have to tell us.

Comment: What datatype does `ls_roomRoomArea` expect? Maybe not a string?

Comment: @Crowcoder the content of "Nutzfläche" is float, but .ToString should convert the float to string

Comment: Yes, but if your List is List<float> you can't add a string to it. But, you haven't said what `ls_roomRoomArea` is exactly.

Comment: Now it is List<string>

Comment: DataTables absolutely support float types. This should be a simple fix but we are not getting the information we need to help. What is the value of `s_roomRoomArea` when your exception happens?

Comment: The value of s_roomRoomArea is "null".     
the exeption message says: Column 'Nutzfläche' does not belong to table Table

Comment: OK, that helps. Your column  name is wrong or your query is not what you think it is. Correct it or use the ordinal position instead of name.

Comment: yeah, it worked with the position!!!! 
thank you sooo much. Maybe the "ä" was the problem...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

Please refer to the following code>

database:

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nutzfläche` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

C# code:

```
namespace MySQLTest
{
    using System.Data;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=<password here>;Database=Test;";
            string selectString = "Select id, Nutzfläche FROM TestTable";
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectString, connectionString);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                string testFloatColumn = dataRow[1].ToString();
                string testFloatColumn2 = dataRow["Nutzfläche"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but i can not modify the database...
p.s. I dont need a datatabel if there is some other way to get to the lists

Comment: @ClemensSteinbauer well I just give You a working example of query. You can change the parts, that You don't have privileges for. You can use it as a helper

Comment: @Crowcoder It's complete example. If any detail missing, than it should help. Or if it's not an answer, than it's an XY problem.

Comment: Since the foreach loop was being executed, OP clearly succeeded in filling a DataTable so that is not the problem and your answer provides no value. Anyway, it was a problem with the column name.

Comment: @Crowcoder how can my answer be with no value, if other answers copying from it?

Comment: also my answer emphasizes on column name checking `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: For reasons I already stated and because you are all wrong. There was not enough information provided to know the problem.

Comment: XY problem You know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to declare the `type` of variable to `float` in mysql.

Try `string s1=float.Parse(DataRow["rowname"].ToString());`
or

```
s1 = Convert.ToDouble( _dr["variable_name"]);
```

this variable name will be the result of your query.

Then the following

```
static void Main()
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=<password here>;Database=Test;";
            string selectString = "Select id, Nutzfläche FROM TestTable";
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectString, connectionString);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                string testFloatColumn = dataRow[1].ToString();
                string testFloatColumn2 = dataRow["Nutzfläche"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: it is a float un

Comment: still the problem persists?

Comment: yes, but I saw that a dataTable can not handle float, is that correct?

Comment: now i've posted one function in my answer  try that..and update me the result

Comment: If still it's there then, share your exception...So that i'll try to solve it.

Comment: what do you mean with "result of your query" my result is the database

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line `string s_roomRoomArea = row["Nutzfläche"].ToString();`

use this line `string s_roomRoomArea = float.Parse(DataRow["rowname"].ToString());`

That is add `float.Parse()` function to your code.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       string s_roomRoomNr = row["Raumnr"].ToString();
       ls_roomRoomNr.Add(s_roomRoomNr);
       string s_roomRoomUser = row["Raumbereich Nutzer"].ToString();
       ls_roomRoomUser.Add(s_roomRoomUser);
       string s_roomRoomArea =float.Parse( row["Nutzfläche"].ToString());
       ls_roomRoomArea.Add(s_roomRoomArea);
    }
```

Comment: how did you define your foreach loop?
bc, now it says: 'DataRow' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Now did you get it?

Comment: Um, you just assigned a float to a string.

Comment: yeah, the problem is, that my programm does not load the float value from the database into my datatable
still, thank you for you help :)